# CSV Exporting SQL results with value 000000 turned to 0

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv, oracle12c

I have a script in executed in SQL Developer.
It is successfully showing '00000000' in columns as shown in the image above but when exported into CSV file, becomes '0'.

Any advise on how I can export the results into CSV and export the results '0000000'?[image]

But when I exported these results into CSV it turned out like as '0' shown image below
[image]

Comment: If that final screenshot is from Excel, then be aware that if Excel decides that the value is numeric, it won't show any leading zeros. I would check what is actually in the file by opening it with Notepad or similar.

Comment: 1) It is table or some expression? 2) Second how do you export it?  Third (last look like an Excel file). You should open it with Notepad and 00000 will be there.

Comment: Add a leading `'` to the returned string. E.g. `SELECT '''' + LATEST_LOGIN_DATE FROM <YourTable>`. Excel will then take the string as is without trying to do some "optimization"

Comment: Thank you guys. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think concatenating a ' character at the front of your field should have an acceptable small performance impact and still retain the 0s for the purposes of viewing in Excel.

Beware it is only Excel trying to helpful that is causing it to do remove leading 0s, if it's not for user in Excel you need to check output in a text editor.